# Why can't Regex match Zip Code pattern in Richtextbox1

Tags: c#, regex, match, zipcode

How come it can't find the Zip code pattern inside richtextbox1? Can't regex look around the richtextbox and find it?

This is the code I used:

```
string text = richTextBox1.Text.ToString();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$");

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))
{
    richTextBox2.Text += match;
}
```

This is the text inside richtextbox1

```
Mr. Underpants
6666 E River Park Dr
South Lake, CA 96150-5117
United States
```

Comment: Remove the `$` and the `^` and magic shall happen.

Comment: AHAHAHA thanks newstack! i haven't really used regex that much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are "anchoring" the regex by using the beginning of input (`^`) and end of input (`$`) metacharacters.

What you are saying, in essense, is match nothing BUT a zip code (with no surrounding text).  Just remove the anchoring characters, and your solution will work:

```
\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation Ethan. I'm not really a user of regex, i just copied it from a code snippet site lol  i just need to use it for this occasion